# Export magento order, custom query

Tags: php, database, magento-1.7

I need to export the following order information in in magento order.I need a query to get the data and export it to a csv file.
Can anyone help? any hints?

Order number, SKU, Item name, Quantity, Item price, Total Line price, Cost of each item(I don't know whether this is a custom attribute or not), Total Line Cost, Order Total Cost, Shipping, Order Total Price

For example

```
1001  SKU1 NAME_1 2 3.00 6.00 2.50 5.00 8.00 3.65 11.65


   SKU2 NAME_2 3 2.00 6.00 1.00 3.00 8.00 3.65 11.65
```

In which #1001 is order number
SKU1, SKU2 are items in that order
2,3 are the quantity of each item
3.00 and 2.00 is the selling price for each item
6.00 is the quantity x the selling price
2.50 and 1.00 are the cost for each item
5.00 and and 3.00 are the cost x the quantity
8.00 is 5 + 3 (order total)
3.65 is the shipping cost
11.65 is the order total

Thanks in advance for your help